# Dynamic Field in Form Grid (X++)

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Currently I have a table which contains input from users, and these input will be shown in a Form.

The case is, I am able to show checkbox in the form manually but as the input from users grows, I need to have the checkbox to be generated automatically. Is there any way to achieve this in X++?[image]

There no restriction whether the checkbox is lined horizontal or vertical, it's just it would be nice if it can be shown as columns.

I wanted to make the checkbox generated automatically so when Table_A have inputs, I don't need to insert a form manually.

This is so when I look at Stall 1, I know what menus it is selling.

Comment: Why can't you just put a check-box per row directly on `Table_A`? Then it would "automatically" have a new checkbox per row... And why are you transposing the rows into columns? I would imagine this has an upper limit.

Comment: Load table A to new table with extra check box field which have relation with your parent table in form and, show the new table with check box in a grid in the form.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I have updated my question with more details. I cannot make a checkbox on Table_A because it will make the items in Table_B will always update and the same row in Table_A. As you can see that I may have many rows in Table_B, and each record in Table_B will update the same record in Table_A if I have the checkbox there correct? @AlexKwitny

Comment: Can you explain more about your idea @PradeepMuttikulangaraVasu? Loading table A in a new table with extra checkbox will result the same as if I add checkbox in Table_A correct?

Comment: If I read this right, it seems like you have your `1:n` relation `Table_A:Table_B` backwards? Instead do `Table_B:Table_A` `(1:n)`. So you would have the same two rows you have pictured in `Table_B`, but in `Table_A` you would have 4 rows, each with checkboxes, where 2 rows pair to `Stall 1` and 2 rows pair to `Stall 2`

Comment: I think Pradeep means that you need an additional table to define a `n:m` relationship between `Table_A` and `Table_B`.

Comment: Yes. @FH-Inway is right. Then only you can capture the user changes on check box and display for all records from Table B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by FH-Inway, you need to create additional table e.g. `Table_ATable_BRelation`. Please find below code to add controls dynamically:

```
form   = formRun.form();
design = form.design();

grpCtrl = design.addControl(FormControlType::Group, #GroupControl);    

while select Table_A
{
    idx++;

    Table_ATable_BRelation = this.findOrCreateRelation(Table_A, Table_B);

    chkBoxCtrl = grpCtrl.addControl(FormControlType::CheckBox, strFmt("CheckBox%1", Table_A.ID));
    chkBoxCtrl.label(Table_A.Food_Menu);
    chkBoxCtrl.labelPosition(LabelPosition::Above);
    chkBoxCtrl.helpText(strFmt("your text here %1.", Table_A.Food_Menu));
    chkBoxCtrl.value(Table_ATable_BRelation.IsSelling);

    chkBoxCtrl.registerOverrideMethod(methodStr(FormCheckBoxControl, clicked),
                                      methodStr(ClassHelper, checkBoxClicked),      
                                      this);
}

grpCtrl.columns(idx);
```